# VPN configuration with same remote and local gatway IP address

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, vpn, routing

I have an issue with VPN routing when the local default gateway is the same as that on the remote network.

Here is the case config:

- VPN network: 192.168.100.0/24
- Remote Services network (reached via VPN): 192.168.0.0/24 gateway
     192.168.0.1
- Local WiFi network (while roaming): 192.168.0.0/24 gateway
     192.168.0.1

The VPN connection works fine if the local network is not the same as the Remote.

In a scenario when Local and Remote are in the same IP range, the VPN connects fine and routes non Remote addresses as intended but routes to local if they are the same.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

So, what I did to solve this is adding a explicit route of the remote network (192.168.0.0/24 in the case above) through the VPN gateway (192.168.100.1 in the above case).

Comment: I suspect, though, this will interfere when the local network has the same address space as the VPN network...